# List of all devices connected to my network

Tags: wi-fi, networking, wifi-hotspot

Is there any way to get list of all devices connected to my Wi-Fi network?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Theres's an app for that. See [Fing](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.overlook.android.fing&hl=en).

Comment: Though I should mention that "Fing" in Hungarian means fart.